recursion in teradata sql (loop)
with
        --my input--
        x(id1,med_id,dt,dt_tm,casemgr_id,casemgr_clntid,status) as (
        select 123456,98410,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 09:00:00',12345,67891,-2
        union all
        select 194567,98410,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 11:00:00',12345,67891,-2
        union all
        select 789101,98410,date'2024-04-24',timestamp'2024-04-24 09:00:00',12345,67891,-2
        union all
        select 194587,98410,date'2024-04-25',timestamp'2024-04-25 09:00:00',12345,67891,-2
        union all
        select 234561,98410,date'2024-04-26',timestamp'2024-04-26 09:00:00',12345,67891,-2
        union all
        select 456789,91956,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 08:00:00',99012,87567,-2
        union all
        select 998415,91956,date'2024-12-20',timestamp'2024-12-20 07:00:00',99012,87567,-2
    union all
      select 01786,18745,date'2023-11-16',timestamp'2023-11-16 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
    union all
      select 01786,18745,date'2023-11-21',timestamp'2023-11-21 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
    union all
      select 01786,18745,date'2023-12-01',timestamp'2023-12-01 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
    union all
      select 01786,18745,date'2023-12-04',timestamp'2023-12-04 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
    union all
      select 01786,18745,date'2024-02-02',timestamp'2024-02-02 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
    union all
      select 01786,18745,date'2024-07-05',timestamp'2024-07-05 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
    union all
      select 01786,18745,date'2024-07-21',timestamp'2024-07-21 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
    union all
      select 01786,18745,date'2024-07-21',timestamp'2024-07-23 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
        );

Input above.
Goal is this:

The code should check the min(dt) for a particular med_id. That record should be valid. If there are two records on the same day, the earlier one should be valid.
Subsequent records within 180 days should be invalid for a combination of med_id and casemgr_clntno. Example: if the min(dt) is 1/1/2024, all subsequent records (combination of med_id and casemgr_clntno) till 6/29/2024 should be invalid.
Then (combination of med_id and casemgr_clntno), If there is a record on 6/30/2024 , that record will be valid and that will become the starting point. If there are any records between 12/27/2024, those will be invalid and so on. In other words, it should function like a loop

So for example in the last three rows, where the record on 5th july is valid since it's the first record after the 180 day time window, so that record is marked as valid in my desired results. but subsequently the next records are invalid (in other words, it has restarted the time window). So the records on 21st July and 23rd july should take the record on 5th july as a starting point
The code below addresses points 1 and 2, but not the recursive loop.
-- sql qry which was suggested---
    SELECT
  id1,
  med_id,
  dt,
  dt_tm,
  casemgr_id,
  casemgr_clntid,
  CASE WHEN dt_tm = MIN(dt_tm) OVER(PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_clntid)
         OR dt_tm >= CAST(MIN(dt_tm) OVER(PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_clntid) AS DATE)
                     + INTERVAL '181' DAY
    THEN 'valid'
    ELSE 'invalid'
  END AS status
FROM x
ORDER BY med_id, casemgr_clntid, dt_tm;





with
        --my desired output--
        x(id1,med_id,dt,dt_tm,casemgr_id,casemgr_clntid,status) as (
        select 123456,98410,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 09:00:00',12345,67891, 'valid'
        union all
        select 194567,98410,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 11:00:00',12345,67891,'invalid'
        union all
        select 789101,98410,date'2024-04-24',timestamp'2024-04-24 09:00:00',12345,67891,'invalid'
        union all
        select 194587,98410,date'2024-04-25',timestamp'2024-04-25 09:00:00',12345,67891,'invalid'
        union all
        select 234561,98410,date'2024-04-26',timestamp'2024-04-26 09:00:00',12345,67891,'invalid'
        union all
        select 456789,91956,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 08:00:00',99012,87567,'valid'
        union all
        select 998415,91956,date'2024-12-20',timestamp'2024-12-20 07:00:00',99012,87567,'valid'
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-11-16',timestamp'2023-11-16 07:00:00',12434,87438,valid
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-11-21',timestamp'2023-11-21 07:00:00',12434,87438,invalid
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-12-01',timestamp'2023-12-01 07:00:00',12434,87438,invalid
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-12-04',timestamp'2023-12-04 07:00:00',12434,87438,invalid
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-02-02',timestamp'2024-02-02 07:00:00',12434,87438,invalid
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-07-05',timestamp'2024-07-05 07:00:00',12434,87438,valid /* this record is valid because it's outside the initial 180 day window */
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-07-21',timestamp'2024-07-21 07:00:00',12434,87438,invalid /*this record is invalid because it's within the 180 day timeframe from 2024-07-05 */
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-07-23',timestamp'2024-07-23 07:00:00',12434,87438,invalid /*this record is invalid because it's within the 180 day timeframe from 2024-07-05 */

        );

The record on 5th july is the first record after the initial 180 day time window and that should be valid and this should be a point of reference and the code should check for subsequent records using the above record as a reference, not the initial time window.
One of the things I'm struggling with is after the initial 180 day time window, how to identify the first record and mark that as a 'Y' or an 'N' so that it becomes a starting point as opposed to the very first record. Can someone please assist with this?

You wrote the following, but it doesn't match your desired results. Then if there are any records with in the 180 day timeframe, those records should be valid, otherwise invalid Please also read [mre]

@MatBailie I modified the question to provide better context and explanation
